# EmberJS - A way to log undefined bindings

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to get Ember to log a warning or error if you reference a property that doesn't exist? Currently if you misspell a the name of a property bound in your handlebar template there is no warning, it just doesn't show anything, and it can be hard to find which property is incorrect.

I have LOG_BINDINGS enabled, which helps somewhat, but there is a lot of unrelated stuff to sort through.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any sort of general built-in debugging that I have found, but there is a mechanism to add your own.

Ember.Object calls a method 'unknownProperty' any time a 'get' call returns undefined. You can add a console.warn to this method to log the property. The documentation describes it as a way to make custom abstract method type handling.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_get

```
Ember.Object.reopen(
  unknownProperty: (property) ->
    unless property is 'App' or property is 'Ember'
      console.warn "Unknown property #{property} in #{@toString()}"
)
```

Notice the filtering of the global namespaces 'App' and 'Ember' - all calls to global properties still go through this interface, but for what we care about they are red herrings.

Unfortunately, if you try to do this by reopening Ember.Object itself, you get a bunch of junk you don't care about, because apparently this happens all the time, especially in the EventManager classes. I have gotten around this by applying it to Ember.ArrayController, Ember.ObjectController, and a Model class that all of my models inherit from.

I now get a neat warning message on the console instead of a blank page every time I accidentally type "hight" into handlebars instead of "height"

In a production solution one would want to link this to some kind of "debug" option in the build, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

One half solution might be to use the `log` handlebars helper to log the property before using it, unfortunately a non existent property causes the template to not display at all. This is a common problem with handlebars not displaying errors.

```
{{log myProperty}}
```

Comment: Sounds useful for debugging.. but it doesn't quite solve the basic problem. I feel like I spend half of my development time in Ember/handlebars looking for typos and similar ;( If handlebars just doesn't have that feature that's too bad.